# Random access random permutations

Tags: partitioning, randomized-algorithms

I have a large number of parallel processes and a large integer $n$, and want to randomly partition the integers $[0,n)$ among the processes with only $O(1)$ communication.

One nice way to do this would to generate a pseudorandom permutation $\pi \in S_n$ represented as a small function, so that only the random key/seed need be exchanged.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: I'm about to answer this myself.  I was about to answer it on stackoverflow, but it was closed as "not a question": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077953/random-access-random-permutations

Comment: Totally cool. I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: One fun bit is that the inverse of the permutation gives which process owns a given index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick $2^k$ slightly larger than $n$, generate a block cypher $f \in S_{2^k}$ operating on $k$ bit blocks, and construct a permutation on $[0,n)$ by walking along cycles of $f$ until we get back in the desired range.  Specifically, given $x < n$ we set
$$g(x) = f^p(x) = f(f(f(...x...)))$$
where $p$ is the least positive integer s.t. $f^p(x) < n$.

If $2^k = O(n)$, and the block cypher is good, the walk takes $O(1)$ expected time.  Note that $p$ is necessarily finite, since eventually we will walk back around the cycle and find $f^p(x) = x$.

For more details, see

1. Black and Rogaway, Ciphers with Arbitrary Finite Domains, 2001.
2. http://blog.notdot.net/2007/9/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-2-Secure-permutations-with-block-ciphers

Here is an example implementation using a truncated TEA block cypher as described in (2):

https://github.com/otherlab/core/blob/f09fbd19dbaa7b9033eb0888594273a6a3d592a5/random/permute.cpp

Comment: Trivial, but I found it interesting: this trick isn't limited to finding [pseudorandom permututations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) of sets of the form $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ but all sorts of weird/wonderful sets. Don't even need to precompute/store the set if it has a simple membership test! Eg to find $g$ that permutes the set $S=\{1677,2717,2977,3757,\dots,9776\}$ of "four-digit numbers divisible by 13 in which the digit 7 appears at least twice", it's enough to note $2^{14}>\max(S)$, take $k=14$, then iterate $f$ until the output passes the membership test for $S$!